# Cannot call use-package on Emacs master

Tags: debugging, use-package

I can't use `use-package` with Emacs master. How can I find out why this is?

For me, all calls (via `eval-last-sexp`) to `use-package` fail as

```
Error (use-package): Cannot load X Disable showing Disable logging
```

where `X` is the package of interest.

How do I get details about the error? `use-package` suppresses the stack trace. Running Emacs with `--debug-init` gives the same results.

Comment: I am using the `-Q` switch. Thanks